# DiscordJS Member Counter Weird Appearance

Tags: discord.js

So I have added member count to the bot but I discovered something a bit strange.
If I use `guild.memberCount` I get the same result as the counter on the server settings page.
But if I use `guild.members.cache.size` I get a different result number.

Example
`guild.memberCount` says 1335 (Same as Server Settings Page)
`guild.members.cache.size` says 1332

Is there a reason why it keeps removing 3?
W do not use bot user filters. Just a total count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all members will be in the cache. Generally, they only become cached once they send a message, at which point they're stored temporarily in memory.

`guild.memberCount`, on the other hand, is the member count directly received from Discord's API.